# Survive during 30+ days without mana

Tags: exodus

A few days ago asked [this question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/54817/27054) with title «How many people left Egypt?» and the given answers state over 2 million persons.

Considering that in Exodus 16:1 (NASB)

> Then they set out from Elim, and all the congregation of the sons of Israel came to the wilderness of Sin, which is between Elim and Sinai, on the fifteenth day of the second month after their departure from the land of Egypt.

we read that mana appeared over 30 days after they left Egypt...

How could they survive that long?

Comment: They left Egypt loaded down with wealth and livestock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ex 12:32-34 says this:

> Take your flocks and herds as well, just as you have said, and depart!
> And bless me also.” And in order to send them out of the land quickly,
> the Egyptians urged the people on. “For otherwise,” they said, “we are
> all going to die!” So the people took their dough before it was
> leavened, carrying it on their shoulders in kneading bowls wrapped in
> clothing.

From this we learn that when the Israelites departed Egypt they had with them at least the following:

- Grain, dough and other food supplies
- flock as herds

These flocks and herds would have easily outnumbered the Israelites and so there would have been millions of head of cattle and sheep and goats.  Thus, provided there was feed for the flocks and herds, there would have been plenty of food at least for a limited time.

Apparently, these food supplies last about one month and then God provided manna (Lev 16).